# Extracting ip address from a file in python and counting how many times the ip shows up

Tags: python

I have to use a text file and extract the most frequent ip address and count how many times they come up

```
    def anaylse_log(parameter):
        
        myfile = open("sample_log_1 test.txt", "r")
        iPdata = myfile.readlines()
        

    mydict = {}
    ipAddress = []
    item_list = []
    result_file = []

    counter = ()

    def extract_log(myfile):
        
        #split the file line by line
        for line in myfile:
            splitData = line.split()
            ipAddress = splitData[0]
            numbers = splitData[1]
        


            ipAddress.append(ipAddress)
            numbers.append(numbers)
            
            if  numbers in mydict:
                #if numbers is already a key in the dictionary

                #increase the count
                mydict[numbers] += 1
            else:
                # Otherwise if it's not yet in the dictionary
                # Initialise it to 1
                mydict[numbers] = 1
                
                return numbers
                
        myfile.close()

    def find_most_frequent(maximum,iPdata):

        with open("sample_log_1 text", "r") as myfile:
            for text in myfile:
                if str(maximum) in text:
                    
                    return maximum

        with open("resultss.csv", "w") as file:
            file.write(maximum(maximum))

             #This will put the dictionary into tuples and give each key a value
            item_list = [(k, v) for k, v in mydict.items()]

            #This will sort the list by v
            item_list.sort(key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

        maximum = mydict()

    def main(myfile,mydict,iPdata):

        result_file = open("resultss.csv", "w")    

        main()
```

i had to fix the spacing for the code to be edited, i hope this is ok and you are able to run it, i have stuck on this for a while and i thought i was calling the functions too

Comment: Your `mydict` is actually a `list`, Python `dict` objects are defined like so: `mydict = {}` using curly braces

Comment: what should it be

Comment: `mydict = {}`, what you're doing in your code is trying to access a value at **index** `numbers` in the `list` `mydict`

Comment: Could you reformat your code ? It may help find an answer to your problem.  Also : you appends numbers to numbers ? What is the purpose ?

Comment: You should also fix your indentation. Right now you `return` in the `else` block of `extrat_log`. It should also be `return numbers` without the `()`. And `myfile.close()` with the `()`

Comment: it was from an older python script i done and thought it would help with extracting the ip addresses, how wold you like it formatted?

Comment: Also, you call `main()` within `main()` and supply no arguments. You also never call any of your other functions. Please update your post to include a code sample that we can copy-paste and run to reproduce your issue. The current version is unusable.

Comment: am trying to edit my code the now to give you an uodated version

Comment: what's the format of the log file where you have your IP addresses? is it a CSV? May be it's easier if you import that as a Pandas DataFrame and compute the stats from there ...

Comment: it is just a text file i have been given to use, the csv is a file i created to show the results in

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually counting IPs as you loop through your log, try this:

```
from collections import Counter
log_entries = open("resultss.csv").read().split("\n")
ip_list = [log.split(",")[0] for log in log_entries]
counts = Counter(ip_list)
print(counts)
```

This works with a CSV file format like:

```
10.10.10.1,asdf,31
5.9.7.11,aajbczxz,54
5.9.7.11,zzzzz,2
```

Comment: File "c:\Users\blair\Desktop\Computer programming\testss.py", line 20, in <module>
    counts = counter(ip_list)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable,   
thats the reply i get from using your code

Comment: I added an example of the CSV file format I assumed. If you post your CSV file's format that will help folks answer the question better.

Comment: result_file = open("results.csv", "w")

Comment: i just opened a new file and saved it with the name result.csv and thats it created

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean. Please edit your original question and add your CSV file. That will help us understand how to read it.

Comment: my csv file was just created while i was using visual studio code, using the command that allows you to create a file open with pytthon, i am needing to access the file and thats has a ip address in the text file and i want to display the most frequent ip addresses with a count of how many times it comes up

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your log file is like

```
15.25.7.3
25.25.2.5
25.25.2.5
115.25.7.3
215.25.7.3
25.25.2.5
```

Here is a simple way to count ips

```
ip_count_dict = {}

with open('ip.log', 'r') as f:
    ip_file = f.read()
    # if separated by coma
    # ip_list = ip_file.split(',')
    # if separated by \n new line
    ip_list = ip_file.splitlines()
    for ip in ip_list:
        ip = ip.strip()
        if ip in ip_count_dict:
            ip_count_dict[ip] += 1
        else:
            ip_count_dict[ip] = 1

print(ip_count_dict)
```

Output: {'15.25.7.3': 1, '25.25.2.5': 3, '115.25.7.3': 1, '215.25.7.3': 1}

Comment: thanks but what about storing the to either the file i wish to show the results in or a variable i can call to show in the file